# Firebase cohorts charts

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics

Can someone describe image below. What scenario make cohorts chart on Mar 6, after day 1, retention rate go over 100%? Is that possible ?

I think the chart show a new users on each day with the time pass and how many user return to the app in percentage.

[image]